# Apache: difference between “Header always set” and “Header set” with Access-Control-Allow-Origin?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, configuration

Context：I want to use apache to add http based authentication and cross-domain access to a directory. **.htaccess** file like：

```
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Credentials "true"
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "http://localhost:8080"
AuthName "Input Passwd!"
AuthType Basic
AuthUserFile users/user.htpasswd
require valid-user
```

It is working. But if I set

```
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "http://localhost:8080"
```

I get

```
The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values 
'http://localhost:8080, *', but only one is allowed. Origin 
'http://localhost:8080' is therefore not allowed access.
```

Looks like it is extra `,*` character. **Why does it cause this difference?**

Has been configured `Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin *` in the http.conf.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Apache: difference between "Header always set" and "Header set"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39502968/apache-difference-between-header-always-set-and-header-set)

Comment: A little different