# How to get around CORS error on a 307 redirect

Tags: php, .htaccess, cors, http-status-code-307

I'm using a 307 redirect `mod_rewrite` rule in my `.htaccess` to redirect all `/api/...` requests to an `apiHandler.php`, and I'm having trouble with CORS.

My `.htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^api/(.*)$ /apiHandler.php [NC,R=307]
```

My `apiHandler.php`

```
<?php

header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:4200");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type");
header("Content-Type: application/json");

...

?>
```

Whenever I make an api request in my front-end, I get a CORS error,

```
"...has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header is present on the request resource."
```

[image: cors issue]

yet I specifically have that header in my `apiHandler.php`, so I don't know what the issue is.

After doing a little bit of research, I've heard that the redirecting URL must also include an `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header, or else the browser will stop right there with its attempted cross-domain request. But I've already tried also adding those headers to my `.htaccess` with no luck.

Any ideas?

Comment: Ensure you’re also adding the Access-Control-Allow-Origin response header to responses for the `/api/students/1/courses` route. Check the response for that in browser devtools to confirm that header is in the response.

Comment: `/api/students/1/courses` isn't a real endpoint though. I want to redirect to `apiHandler.php` to dissect the REST api url so I can route to the correct REST noun.

Comment: @sideshowbarker so since it isn't a real endpoint, I'm not able to add headers to it, if that makes any sense.

Comment: Yeah, I see now. So have you tried adding the headers in our .htaccess instead? If  you can, please trying adding in your .htaccess: `header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "http://localhost:4200"\n header always set Access-Control-Allow-Credentials "true"\n header always set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "Content-Type"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you [@sideshowbarker](https://stackoverflow.com/users/441757/sideshowbarker)! The solution to my problem was removing the headers from my `apiHandler.php` and adding them to my `.htaccess`.

```
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "http://localhost:4200"
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Credentials "true"
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "Content-Type"
Header always set Content-Type "application/json"

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^api/(.*)$ /apiHandler.php [NC,R=307]
```

Notice the use of `Header always set ...` instead of `Header set ...`. This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39551910/6128284) explains the difference between the two.