# How to fix ‘The frame being accessed is sandboxed and lacks the "allow-same-origin" flag'

Tags: iframe, safari, sandbox

In Safari when executing this code

```
iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document
```

I get an error

> Sandbox access violation: Blocked a frame at "My url" from accessing a frame at "null".  The frame being accessed is sandboxed and lacks the "allow-same-origin" flag.

This is how an iframe is formed:

```
'<iframe name="'+name+'" id="'+name+'" src="'+src+'" sandbox="allow-same-origin">'
```

In debugger I can get the property iframe.sanbox with given value

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The browser automatically blocks the website from loading based on the website's preferences. The website you are trying to load must set:

```
X-Frame-Options: DENY
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
```

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42788173/1457219).